# cakephp validation view issue?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

First post here on stack overflow so I hope I do it right, I have searched but cannot find what I am looking for.

i am new to cakephp and fairly new to php.  I was able to get up and running yesterday no problem and can send data to my database. to day I wanted to work on validation with ajax but I think I am going to leave the ajax out of it for a little while as I have a problem with the validation errors displaying.

The validation is set up for the first two form fields like this;

```
<?php 

class people extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'people';
    public $useTable = 'people';

    public $validate = array(
        'firstName'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'Enter You First Name'
            ),
        'secondName'=>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'message'=>'Enter Your Second/Family Name'
            ),
        );
}?>
```

and it works fine if those fields are empty it wont write to the database so far so good.  However, when I hit submit on the form the page refreshes, the error messages appear under the form fields but it also adds a completely new form under the previous one.  here is the controller.  Note: the validate_form function is from an cakephp with ajax tutorial i was following and is commented out

```
<?php 

class peoplesController extends AppController
{
    public $name = "peoples";
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'form', 'Js');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');



     public function index() {


            if( $this->request->is('post'))
            {
                $data = $this->request->data;
                $this->people->save($data);


            }

        }

    /*public function validate_form() {
            if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $this->data['people'][$this->params['form']['field']] = $this->params['form']['value'];
                $this->people->set($this->data);
                if ($this->people->validates()) {
                    $this->autoRender = FALSE;
                }
                else {
                    $error = $this->validateErrors($this->people);
                    $this->set('error', $error[$this->params['form']['field']]);
                }

        }
    }*/

    }

    ?>
```

and the view.  note: the divs with id sending and success are also from the tutorial I was following but I dont think would have an effect on this particular issue.

```
    <div id="success"></div>
<h2> Fill in your profile details </h2>

    <?php 
echo $this->Form->create('people');

echo $this->Form->input('firstName');
echo $this->Form->input('secondName');
echo $this->Form->input('addressOne');
echo $this->Form->input('addressTwo');
echo $this->Form->input('city');
echo $this->Form->input('county');
echo $this->Form->input('country');
echo $this->Form->input('postCode', array(
        'label' => 'Zip Code',
    ));
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array(
        'label' => 'Date of birth',
        'dateFormat' => 'DMY',
        'minYear' => date('Y') - 70,
        'maxYear' => date('Y') - 18,
    ));
echo $this->Form->input('homePhone');
echo $this->Form->input('mobilePhone');
echo $this->Form->input('email', array(
        'type' => 'email'
    ));

$goptions = array(1 => 'Male', 2 => 'Female');
$gattributes = array('legend' => false);

echo $this->Form->radio('gender', 
    $goptions, $gattributes
    );

echo $this->Form->input('weight');
echo $this->Form->input('height');

$toptions = array(1 => 'Tandem', 2 => 'Solo');
$tattributes = array('legend' => false);

echo $this->Form->radio('trained',
    $toptions, $tattributes
    );

echo $this->Form->input('referedBy');

/*echo $this->Form->submit('submit');*/

echo $this->Js->submit('Send', array(

    'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
    'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
    'update'=>'#success'

    ));

echo $this->Form->end();
     ?>
     <div id="sending" style="display: none; background-color: lightgreen">Sending....           </div>

    <?php

echo $this->Html->script(
    'validation', FALSE); 
     ?>
```

so the creation of the second identical form on the same page is my primary problem, I think it has something to do with the controller taking the first form and sending it back to the same view but I dont know how to trouble shoot this.

a second problem is that for some reason if I use

```
echo $this->Form->submit('submit');
```

instead of

```
echo $this->Js->submit('send', array(
'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
'success'=>$this->Js->get('sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
'update'=>'#success'));
```

Then I dont get my error messages anymore I instead just get a bubble that appears and says 'please fill in this field'  I am sure this is a jquery issue but again I dont know how to trouble shoot it so that that bullbe does not appear and it instead shows the error messages I want

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

1) Use Caps for your classnames.  So `People`, `PeoplesController`, etc

2) Don't mess with Ajax until you get the standard flow working.  So go back to `$this->Form->submit('submit');`.

3) That "required" tooltip is HTML5. Since you set the validation to `notEmpty`, Cake adds HTML5 markup to make the field required. Modify your `Form->create` call to bypass that for now (if you need to, but it provides client-side validation which is more efficient):

```
$this->Form->create('People', array('novalidate' => true));
```

[See the FormHelper docs for more info on HTML5 validations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper%3a%3ainput)

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it, the reason I didn't use caps was because my database fields were not caps, I can assume that dosn't make a difference then?

Comment: No, classnames are not linked to database fields.  Model classname is linked to db **tables**, but they're always converted to lowercase.